# 503 errors when trying to login on local Google AppEngine server

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have a functional Go app which I've been running locally for months. Got setup with Google Cloud, did a test run to a live domain, everything works.

Looking back at my local machine, I want to run a [local Google AppEngine server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/tools/using-local-server) (instead of running my Go app directly). It runs, however I'm trying to use the "login: required" parameter in app.yaml, and I see the login form at localhost:8080, however no matter what email I input, it keeps timing out with 503 errors.

My app.yaml:

```
application: myapp-dev
env: flex
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /
  script: _go_app
  login: required
```

Command I use to run the local app:

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

Comment: I'm getting the same issue running Google's untouched Hello World sample app.  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexible environment doesn't support 'login' features via app.yaml (external to whatever regular login you'd do in your app).

Standard environment app.yaml doc **DOES list 'login' features**: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref

Flexible environment app.yaml doc **DOES NOT list 'login' features**: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml

But more specifically, a page talking about upgrading from Standard-to-Flex, mentions that the **login handlers for flex have been deprecated**:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/upgrading

> The login setting under handlers is now deprecated for the App Engine
>   flexible environment. You should follow the guidance for User service
>   migration.

So basically, with flex environment, there is no project-wide login controls possible outside of your app. You have to let the app initialize and then do normal authentication/authorization.

For my own project, I wanted a quick app-wide level of security so I could provide guest accounts and have them see what a public not-logged-in view of my app would be. Yes I can do the same within my app, I just wanted to save some work.